# NetworkD3 Sankey Diagram in R: How to display different sub-categories of the dataset in a sankey diagram in LinkGroup?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I am working on making a sankey diagram in R, but having trouble with the `LinkGroup` code. I attach parts of my code which should explain the problem and the head of the data. I have a current plot without the legend of products, and I also attach what I eventually want R to do automatically with the `LinkGroup` function (right now I constructed the legend manually for illustration).

I currently have a sankey diagram with source and target (countries), with products ('major_prod') transferred between the source and target. I want to show the legend containing the different products transferred (beef, palm oil, wheat etc.)

Here is a reproducible example. The problem remains that the sankey has colour, but the legend of the product (Meat, palm oil, rice nuts etc.) does not show.

```r
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(magrittr)
library(networkD3)
library(tidyr)

Sankey <- data.frame("origin" = c('country A', 'country A', 'country A', 'country A', 'country B', 'country B', 'country C', 'country C'),
"destination" = c('country B', 'country B', 'country C', 'country D', 'country D', 'country D', 'country E', 'country E'),
'product' = c('Meat', 'Palm oil', 'Meat', 'Meat', 'Wheat', 'Other', 'Rice', 'Nuts'),
'number' = c(10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 35, 50,10)) 

nodes <- as.data.frame(union(unique(Sankey$origin), unique(Sankey$destination))) %>%
rename(Countries = 1)

Sankey$ID_major_Origin_EU <- match(Sankey$origin, nodes$Countries)-1 
Sankey$ID_major_Destination_EU <- match(Sankey$destination, nodes$Countries)-1

Sankey$ID_major_Origin_EU <- match(Sankey$origin, nodes$Countries)-1 
Sankey$ID_major_Destination_EU <- match(Sankey$destination, nodes$Countries)-1

head(Sankey)
nodes %<>% tidyr::separate(Countries, "Countries", sep = "_")

sankeyNetwork(Links = Sankey, 
          Nodes = nodes, 
          Source = "ID_major_Origin_EU", Target = "ID_major_Destination_EU", 
          Value = "number", NodeID = "Countries",
          units = "t dm", fontSize = 20, nodeWidth = 30,
          height = 600,
          #sinksRight = T,
          LinkGroup = c("product")) %>%
htmlwidgets::prependContent(htmltools::tags$h1("2013 - embodied HANPP"))
```

I want to show a legend containing the 'product' on the side of the sankey diagram but I cannot find a way. Any hints or solutions?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Do you want to add a legend? Do you want to know how to use the LinkGroup argument properly? It would also be much easier for someone to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example... meaning providing a small but representative sample of the data you're working with.

Comment: @cjyetman Thanks for your response! I have edited my original question to make it clearer.

Comment: I still don't quite understand.... your example does not produce a plot with a legend. And the `sankeyNetwork()` function does not have the capability to produce a legend by itself. So, is your question "how do I add a legend to the Sankey plot?"?

Comment: @cjyetman yes basically that is my question! sorry for running around in circles. the sankey does not seem to built for adding legends, although that is something I would like to do.